# Plotting a cycloid does not output a plot

Tags: plotting

This is my first time  evaluating Mathematica to study differential geometry (Curves and Geometry by Alfred Gray) before I consider buying the Mathematica cloud version. I simply wish to plot a cycloid

```
cycloid[a_,b_][t_] := {a t - b Sin[t], a - b Cos[t]};
α = cycloid[1, 1];
ParametricPlot[α[t], {t, -3 π, 3 π}, 
  PlotRange->{{-3 π, 3 π} {-2, 4}}, Ticks -> None]
```

However, it outputs a blank as shown

[image]

Comment: ...and where is the definition of `cycloid`?

Comment: @J.M. sorry I omitted a line. It is edited.

Comment: Use `:=` for the definition of `cycloid`, and `=` for the definition of `α`.

Comment: Same issue. I have edited it again.

Comment: @user9106985 Missing `,` in PlotRange definition!

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo.

Comment: `Manipulate[ParametricPlot[cycloid[a, b][t], {t, -3 \[Pi], 3 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {{-3 Pi, 3 Pi}, {-5, 5}}, Frame -> True], {{a, 1}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Answer (score 3):

Try this particular set first:

```
a = 2; b = 1; cycloid[ t_] := {a  t - b Sin[t], a - b Cos[t]};
ParametricPlot[
  cycloid[t], {t, -3 π, 3 π}, PlotRange -> All, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.2
]
```